# PHP / MySQL PM System with multiple recipients table structure?

Tags: php, mysql, table-structure, private-messaging

I'm currently developing a PM system for a website, in which users must be able to send PM's to multiple recipients. Naturally, this means that if a message has been sent to user A, B and C, user C could delete the message while user A and B won't.
The question is what would be the best database table structure for such a system, of course avoiding multiple copies of one message.
Currently I've thought of this table structure:

```
msgid (int),
parentid (int),
timestamp (timestamp),
senderid (int),
recipients (varchar),
subject (varchar)
text (text),
deletedby (varchar),
readby (varchar)
```

This would be the only table. Threads are created based on the parentid's (if there is no parentid the message is the first in a thread), and ordered by timestamp. Recipients are stored comma-separated in one column and checked by using WHERE userid IN (msg.recipients). The deletedby column contains all id's (comma-separated) of users which have deleted the message, just like the readby column.

However I am not sure if this is an ideal table structure. Before I start coding I would like to hear your thoughts for improvements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing CSV values in a single field is invariably a bad design and will just cause you severe pain. Normalize the design now, before you roll out the system for production: put the recipients list into a child table, and put a "deleted" flat on the child record to indicate whether that particular recipient deleted the message or not:

```
recipientsTable

messageID    int -> foreign key to messages table
recipientID   int -> foreign key to users table
read     bit - t = read, f = unread
deleted   bit - t = deleted, f = still there.
readON    date - timestamp of when recipient read message
```

... or something similar.

Comment: OK so in short, you suggest having two tables, one with the messages and one in which a row is inserted for each receipient, correct?

Comment: Yes. Having comma-separated values in a field is highly painful if you need to modify the list. Searching isn't so bad, as mysql has find_in_set(), but on other DB systems, it gets ugly fast. Removing a particular value from the csv is painful regardless of the underlying system.

Comment: Allright, thank you. And what do you think about the thread system? Is the parentid and timestamp-ordering model in my example okay?

Comment: sounds serviceable. recursive structures get painful in sql when you start layering the children fairly deeply, though.

Comment: True, could you think of an easier way to do this?

Comment: There's ways to do tree structures in SQL, but each has different benefits/drawbacks. I wouldn't worry about it too much, unless you're doing a "traverse the message history" operation frequently. For one or two levels, it's not a big deal. If you get lots of message threads going 200+ levels deep, THEN start worrying.

Comment: Okay, I'm now thinking of making another table containing the replies, having a column mainid as foreign key to the 'main' messageid in the messages table. Would this be a decent solution?

Comment: Same problem. e.g message #300 is a reply to message #200 is a reply to message #100 is a reply to message #50, etc... Unless you want to disallow this kind of nesting, or put limits on it, eventually you'll get some kind of insanely nested conversation.